# Custom sorting list of strings (following Chamorro language collation rules)

Tags: java, internationalization, collation

I am trying to sort a list of strings for a Pacific island language (Chamorro). In this language, `Ng` is considered one letter, and it comes after `N` in the alphabet. How can I sort a list of words such that `Nai` and `Nunu` both come before words that begin with `Ng`?

**Update**

The complete alphabet is:

```
A, Å, B, Ch, D, E, F, G, H, I, K, L, M, N, Ñ, Ng, O, P, R, S, T, U, Y
```

Besides `Å`, `Ñ`, and their lowercase versions, there are no accents over the other letters. Words can have apostrophes in them (such as `o'mak`), but they don't affect the sort order.

There is no locale for Chamorro, so I need to manually implement a sort algorithm.

Comment: Is there a locale for that language?

Comment: Nope, no locale exists.

Comment: Do you have a full set of rules? And maybe some example words?

Comment: Customized collation rules might help. Have a look at this post: http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-internationalization/collator.html

Comment: Custom Comparator/Comparable and assign that character Ng higer order in alphabet.. http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-object-sorting-example-comparable-and-comparator/

Comment: @JetAbe I think the whole problem here is how does he assign the character a higher order.

Comment: Its already answered by @DirkLachowski Collate and sort

Comment: The link posted by @DirkLachowski looks perfect for what you need?

Comment: no locale exists, cool !

Comment: @DirkLachowski I'll take a look at that link. I think it will work. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to Dirk Lachowski, I implemented a solution that works. Here's what I wrote:

```
  static final String CHAMORRO_RULES = ("< a,A < å,Å < b,B < ch,Ch < d,D < e,E < f,F < g,G < h,H < i,I < k,K < l,L "
      + "< m,M < n,N < ñ,Ñ < ng,Ng < o,O < p,P < r,R < s,S < t,T < u,U < y,Y");
  static final RuleBasedCollator CHAMORRO_COLLATOR;
  static {
    try {
      CHAMORRO_COLLATOR = new RuleBasedCollator(CHAMORRO_RULES);
    }
    catch (ParseException pe) {
      throw new RuntimeException(pe);
    }
  }
```

After I implemented the rule-based collator above, I simply wrote the following sort method:

```
  static void sort(List<String> words) {
    Collections.sort(words, new Comparator<String>() {

      @Override
      public int compare(String lhs, String rhs) {
        return Constants.CHAMORRO_COLLATOR.compare(lhs, rhs);
      }

    });
  }
```